# Make Bordered Login Form and Blurred Background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make my login form have border and center position

Also how to make the background-image blurred

Im using Razor View Engine, ASP MVC

CSS

```css
<style>
    body {
    background-image: url('/Content/HomeImage/Logo New CBN.png');
    margin: 0;
    background-size: 1350px 700px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>

Html
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4>User</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        @Html.Captcha(3)
                        <br />
                        <p class="Error" style="color:red">  @ViewBag.ErrMessage </p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGRg0.png)

I already tried modal style but its not working...

I suspect the HTML Helper which cancel all change towards it

https://jsfiddle.net/g6b8ctbc/1/

Comment: If you repost your rendered code, without razor tags, we can help you

Comment: I dont understand, so I create another thread without razor tag ?

Comment: Done, or do you mean i rewrite the code without '@HtmlHelper' ?

Comment: No, click "edit" under your post (it's a grey link) and then edit your jsfiddle in the poast.

Comment: Owh i dont have any jsfiddle account and jsfiddle doesnt support HtmlHelper

Comment: You don't need a jsfiddle account. Remove your razor code from the fiddle link you posted and i can have a look.

Comment: Done, so I cant implement CSS on a "@Html." ?

Comment: Render your code to a browser and then post it here so there are no razor tags.

Comment: Please just post plain/rendered HTML code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for applying a blur to the background image create a new div to place below everything.

Here you can find the working code:

```css
.background-image {
    background-image: url('https://yt3.ggpht.com/-v0soe-ievYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/OixOH_h84Po/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg');
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: block;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}

.panel{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #555;
    height: 300px;
    max-width: 330px;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index:2;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-image"></div>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4>User</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
             
                <div class="form-group">
                   Username
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    Password
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="password">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        
                        <br />

                        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "panel heading"? And what should it do?

Comment: panel class from bootstrap

Comment: It should, we just play with some CSS :)